# Lifting homology classes to the unit tangent bundle, a la Johnson

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a oriented smooth closed 2-manifold, and let $\gamma$ be an oriented smooth simple closed curve in $M$.

In [Spin structures and quadratic forms on surfaces](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/palestine/johnson-spin-structures.pdf), Johnson definines a standard way of creating a lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ to the unit tangent bundle $UM$, given by taking the foward facing unit tangent field on $\gamma$ and completing it to a frame at every point.

Johnson proves that if $\alpha_i, 1\leq i \leq m$ and $\beta_i, 1 \leq j \leq n$ are two families of simple closed curves in $M$ (the curves being mutually disjoint in each family) such that $\sum_{i= 1}^m \alpha_i$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j$ are homologous in $M$ (mod 2), then in terms of lifts we have

$$ \sum_{i= 1}^m \tilde{\alpha}_i + mz  \text{ and } \sum_{j=1}^n \tilde{\beta}_j + nz$$
are homologous in $UM$ (mod 2), where $z$ should be thought of as a generic "fiber" (the lift of an arbitrarily small circle in $M$).

For this proof Johnson defines a set of basic moves for passing from $\sum_{i= 1}^m \alpha_i$ to $\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j$. One of them is the band change, which looks like this: if $u,v$ are two arcs contained in curves of $\alpha_i$ (not necessarily different curves) connected by an arc $w$ orthogonal to the curves where it meets them (and doesn't meet any other curves), you can replace $u$ and $v$ by $x$ and $y$:
[image]

He then discusses lifting this to $UM$. In the case when $u$ and $v$ have opposite orientations wrt $w$, (as shown below)[image]

it is claimed that a set of homologies in $UM$ corresponding to this move looks like this:
[image]

But i'm really not sure as to what this means. First, how do we overlap the curves, and why can we break of the small circle?

I guess the basic case I'm trying to understand is the following:

[image]

Here $u+v$ is clearly homologous to $t$ (by a band change, or the obvious boundary). How does this homology lift to $UM$?